# ngx-datatable Get latest clicked raw with multiClick mode

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

I am trying to get the latest 'clicked' raw from ngx-datatable. Currently, I have

```
<ngx-datatable
   [rows]="rows"
   [selected]="selected"
   [selectionType]="'multiClick'"
   (select)='onSelect($event)'
   (dblclick)='onDoubleClick($event)'
>
```

Since the selected raws are stored in 'raws' one thing that almost works is to get the latest selected like so:

```
const latest = selected[selected.length - 1];
```

the thing is that when the latest clicked raw is deselected (was selected sometime before) it gets out of the 'selected' array and this is no longer true. Is there some other way to tackle this in order to get the latest 'clicked' raw.

Comment: Is there a way to do it from the event? (I have multiple columns so I am not sure can I get the id somehow) I can also monitor the array and make calculations what goes in and what goes out but it should have a better solution I am sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant the *last selected row*, you already have the answer, you just need to place `const latest = selected[selected.length - 1];` inside the onSelect() function.

E.g.

```
onSelect({ selected }) {
   this.selected.splice(0, this.selected.length);
   this.selected.push(...selected);

   const latest = this.selected[this.selected.length - 1];
   console.log('Latest', latest)
}
```

Because an array is indexed, if you're accessing by the last index, you will always get the "last selected row".

However, if you meant to get the *last clicked row* (regardless if user is selecting or deselecting the row), then you can do so with the onActivate() event handler.

E.g.

```
onActivate(event) {
   if(event.type === "click"){
     console.log(event.row)
   }
}
```

This will give you the "last clicked row" be it if user is selecting or deselecting the row.

You will also need to bind activate event to your onActivate()

```
<ngx-datatable>
   ...
   (activate)="onActivate($event)
   ...
</ngx-datatable>
```